# Zend-framework controller containing both HTML interfaces and REST interfaces

Tags: php, zend-framework, rest, web-applications

I'm developing a web application using Zend-framework. I'm looking for a smart solution to implement both RESTful interfaces and non-RESTful interfaces into a single controller.

Let's pretend we're developing a web application which manages a bunch of paper magazine information. First of all, I want my website to show all registered magazines, formatted in HTML, by accessing the following path.

```
GET /magazine/
```

Also, I want an HTML form to modify new/existing magazine information by

```
GET /magazine/modify/new
GET /magazine/modify/3  (HTML form filled with magazine information where ID=3)
```

and add|update by pressing the "submit" button, which implicitly calls the following path

```
POST /magazine/modify
```

...and redirects to /magazine/. Finally, I want an RESTful interface which supports HEAD/GET/POST/PUT/DELETE magazine information in JSON format, as shown below.

```
HEAD /magazine/rest
GET /magazine/rest    (All magazine information in list)
GET /magazine/rest/3  (One single magazine information where ID=3)
POST /magazine/rest
PUT /magazine/rest/new
PUT /magazine/rest/3
DELETE /magazine/rest/3
```

My only idea was to prepare all actions in a single controller class, which derives Zend_Controller_Action.

```php
class SlipController extends Zend_Controller_Action{
    public function init(){}

    public function indexAction(){
        /* Load all magazine information from model and show. */
        $magazine_mapper = new Application_Model_MagazineMapper();
        $this->view->magazines = $magazine_mapper->fetchAll();
    }

    public function modifyAction(){
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $form = new Application_Form_Magazine();
        if($request->isPost()){
            if($form->isValid($request->getPost())){
                /* Modify magazine information. */
                $modified_magazine = new Application_Model_Magazine($form->getValues());
                $magazine_mapper = new Application_Model_MagazineMapper();
                $magazine_mapper->save($modified_magazine);
                return $this->_helper->redirector('index');
            }
        }else{
            /* Load and prepare form values from Application_Model_Magazine. */
        }
        $this->view->form = $form;
    }

    public function restAction(){
        switch($this->getRequest()->getMethod()){
            case 'HEAD':   /* Do for method HEAD   */ break;
            case 'GET':    /* Do for method GET    */ break;
            case 'POST':   /* Do for method POST   */ break;
            case 'PUT':    /* Do for method PUT    */ break;
            case 'DELETE': /* Do for method DELETE */ break;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that this solution lets me implement each REST action. I've also heard about a nice class called Zend_Rest_Controller, which (I heard that it) makes it easier to implement RESTful interfaces, but this class seems to be used with Zend_Rest_Route, so I have no idea where to put the non-RESTful actions in this way.

I want to know the best practice for such situations. If something gets better by using router hacks, or some other solutions, I want to know how it can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why the insistence on putting everything in the same controller?

`GET /magazine/rest/3` seems rather backward to me. The URL path should have diminishing scope, i.e., from least specific to most specific. I'd do it as `GET /rest/magazine/3` instead. This would allow you to use [`modules`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.modular.html), one for the web app and one for REST:

```
/application/modules/app/controllers
    MagazineController.php
        indexAction()
        editAction()
        newAction()

/application/modules/rest/controllers
    MagazineController.php
        getAction()
        putAction()
        postAction()
        headAction()
```

Comment: Oh, I've never had an idea of using `modules`... I will give it a try! Thanks!!

Comment: Still, would it be possible to have a controller providing both? From what I understood so far, the only difference between a Html and a Rest/Http controller is the base class it extends (and I expect the Html base controller uses a view to "decorate" the ViewModel returned by the controller subclass).

Comment: That's the difference in the way they're executed, yes. But the difference in the service they provide is much more significant, and should be separated logically. I.e., sure it's possible, but if you put all your app's actions into one giant controller then you're defeating the point of using an MVC design.